# Golang calling CUDA library

Tags: c++, go, cuda

I am trying to call a CUDA function from my Go code.
I have the following three files.

test.h:

```
int test_add(void);
```

test.cu:

```
__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c){
       *c = *a + *b;
}

int test_add(void) {
       int a, b, c; // host copies of a, b, c
       int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c; // device copies of a, b, c
       int size = sizeof(int);
       // Allocate space for device copies of a, b, c
       cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
       cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
       cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size);
      // Setup input values
      a = 2;
      b = 7;

      // Copy inputs to device
      cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      // Launch add() kernel on GPU
     add<<<1,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);
     // Copy result back to host
     cudaMemcpy(&c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     // Cleanup
     cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);
    return 0;
}
```

test.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

//#cgo CFLAGS: -I.
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ltest
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -lcudart
//#include <test.h>
import "C"


func main() {
     fmt.Printf("Invoking cuda library...\n")
     fmt.Println("Done ", C.test_add())
}
```

I am compiling CUDA code with:

```
nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -o libtest.so --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC test.cu
```

All three files - test.h, test.cu and test.go are in the same directory.
The error I am getting when I try to build with go is "undefined reference to `test_add'".

I have very little experience with C/C++ and am a total novice in CUDA.

I've been trying to solve my problem for two days now and would be
very grateful for any input.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with go, but it may be a C vs. C++ linking issue.  Try wrapping your `test_add()` prototype in `extern "C" { ... }`

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Where do you see C code? CUDA is C++ based.

Comment: @Olaf where did I say "I see C code." ?  I'm aware that CUDA uses C++ style linkage.  If by chance [the go import of `C` is expecting the function to be provided with C style linkage](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C), then you would run into this problem.  It's just a guess.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: thanks man, I tried your suggestion and it works. You're a life saver : )

Comment: kudos for providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your very first SO posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears, at least in this case, that  [the go import of `C` is expecting the function to be provided with C style linkage](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C).

CUDA (i.e. nvcc) mainly follows C++ patterns and provides by default C++ style linkage (including function name mangling, etc.)

It's possible to force a section of code to be provided externally using C rather than C++ style linkage using `extern "C" {...code...}`.   This is a C++ language feature and not specific to CUDA or nvcc.

Therefore it appears the problem can be solved via the following modification to the test.cu:

```
extern "C" { int test_add(void) { ... code ... }; }
```

Comment: For me the solution works if I use `extern "C" {...code...} ` in test.cu file. But if I include `extern "C"` in header test.h I get an error `./test.h:1:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant`. So I will go with `extern "C"` in cuda files (.cu) which seems to work for me. Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the answer to reflect your usage.  I'm not an expert in this but I think your question could be useful for future readers as a canonical "how do I connect go to CUDA" type question.