# Call cuda library on windows

Tags: c++, go, cuda

I am trying to use cuda to parallelize a Go project.
I've read [Golang calling CUDA library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758750/golang-calling-cuda-library) many times.

I'm trying to do the same thing on Windows and having trouble. (I'm assuming this OP was using Linux because of the `.so` files)

I have successfully compiled/run the following test program involving no cuda code to make sure I have CGO working correctly.

**test.cpp**

```
extern "C"{
    int testfunc(){
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

compiled with g++

```
 g++  test.cpp -o test.dll --shared
```

**callC.go**

```
package main

//int testfunc();
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ltest
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.testfunc())
}
```

prints 1000 - great!

now I try the same thing with `nvcc` and I get an error from ld that theres an undefined reference to testfunc.

**test.cu**

```
extern "C"
{
  int testfunc()
  {
    return 1 + 1;
  }
}
```

compiled with
`nvcc test.cu -o testcuda.dll --shared --compiler-options -fPIC` ... I always get:

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
Creating library testcuda.lib and object testcuda.exp
```

**callCudaC.go**

```
package main

//int testfunc();
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ltestcuda
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -LC:\temppath\CUDA\v11.2\ -lcudart
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.testfunc())
}
```

running this go code results in

`` C:\Users\MICHAE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build045526290\b001\_x002.o: In function `_cgo_701f531a6502_Cfunc_testfunc': /tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:52: undefined reference to `testfunc' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

you'll note that my "cuda" code doesn't involve any cuda, just one exported function and that I tried moving the cuda installation to a simpler path so I could actually pass it as a directory to the linker - I'm not sure if it's even needed since there is no use of cuda syntax etc.

Would be appreciative of debugging tips or hints if anyone has seen this before.

Comment: You do understand that the CUDA toolchain on Windows requires and uses the visual C++ compiler? So in your nvcc example, you are implicitly trying to mix gnu and MS toolchains. Does your non-CUDA version work if you use the MS toolchain?

Comment: @talonmies thanks for your comment - I will test it, do you think I will also need to redirect CGO to use the MS toolchain?

Comment: @talonmies to confirm - I tried my non cuda example, but built it with cl.exe and encountered the same linker error from my go program. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: That is what I suspected would happen. It will come down to understanding how the two toolchains interact. I can't help you with that, I don't use windows. But if you search you might find examples of Go combined with VS libraries you can use to deduce a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the direction from @talonmies comments I found that at least in simple cases I could call the dlls created by cl.exe and nvcc.exe from cgo by defining a header file that looks like this:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {  // only need to export C interface if
              // used by C++ source code
#endif

 __declspec(dllexport) int  testfunc();
 
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

this code was created referencing these two MSDN articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-cpp-functions-for-use-in-c-language-executables?view=msvc-160

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-c-functions-for-use-in-c-or-cpp-language-executables?view=msvc-160